# Laravel - Como fazer um try/catch na view?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, view

Existe alguma maneira de fazer algum `try/catch` em uma `view` do `Laravel 4`?
Como poderia fazer para implementar na sintaxe do `blade`?

Gostaria de algo como:

```
@try
<div class="laravel test">
    {{ $usuario->nome }}
</div>
@catch(Exception $e)
    {{ $e->getMessage() }}
@endtry
```

Answer (score 2):

Não é o correto fazer try/catch na view. A ideia é você sempre retornar algo para ela para que não precise fazer essa validação.

Você pode verificar se a variável possui valor, se possuir exibe o valor dela, se não, não.

```
@if $usuario->nome
    {{$usuario->nome}}
@endif
```

ou então

```
{{$usuario->nome or 'Nome não informado'}}
```

Comment: Me responderam isso no SOEN. Mas, como eu também disse lá, digo aqui: Eu sei que é errado, mas eu gostaria de saber isso por causa da curiosidade de saber fazer isso no compilador do Blade

Comment: Entendi. Tu pode escrever o php normal lá. O blade não tem o @try, mas se tu jogar o php lá ele vai funcionar normalmente.

Comment: Amigo, na verdade que eu queria algo que eu possa fazer com [Blade Extension](http://blog.zerilliworks.net/blog/2013/07/10/blade-extensions-in-laravel-4/)